# Internal server error when enable CCC in advance parameter->performance in prestashop

Tags: performance, prestashop, internal-server-error

I'm using `prestashop 1.6`, for reducing loading time of `website` I enabled all CCC in `advance parameter->performance` in backoffice.

Now I'm getting `500-internal server error` in front and back-office.
 when I open my front office it's getting `500-internal server error`. Even now I can't able to `disable CCC` in backoffice, when I click `advance parameter->performance` getting 500 internal server error.
I cleared caches in browser and in my files also but it's not working.

Tell me how can I disable CCC.

Answer (score 1):

Values are stored at database, at table

```
PREFIX_configuration
```

Set value 0 for the following keys:

```
PS_CSS_THEME_CACHE
PS_JS_THEME_CACHE
```

You could also turn on debugging to see why it's returning a 500 error: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/224525-how-to-turn-on-error-reporting-for-debug-information-blank-page-500-internal-server-error/

Answer (score 0):

my problem got solved it is simple i just removed old `.htaccess` file in website and added new `.htaccess` file. now it is working fine...

Comment: How have you generated new .htaccess?

Comment: i took .htaccess from `prestashop` files